# Command substitution and $PATH variable

Tags: bash, path, command-substitution

**Background**

This [[ article ]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) says :

> The command substitution expands to the output of commands. These
>   commands are executed in a **subshell** ..

But the bash manual says nothing about a `subshell` in its command substitution section.

My test below

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
26483 pts/25   00:00:00 bash
26866 pts/25   00:00:00 ps
$ hpid="$(ps | grep bash)"
$ echo "$hpid"
26483 pts/25   00:00:00 bash
26899 pts/25   00:00:00 bash
```

shows that a new shell with pid 26899 was spawned during the command substitution. At this point I changed the `PATH` environment variable.

```
$ PATH="/some/rogue/path"
```

did the below stuff :

```
VAR="$(echo "Do|Die" | cut -d"|" -f 2)"
```

and got the below error :

```
Command 'cut' is available in '/usr/bin/cut'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cut: command not found
```

I understand that the error is due to the modification of PATH environment variable which helps the shell locate the binaries. However I am confused when reading this together with command substitution.

If by `$(..)` a subshell is spawned, then PATH environment variable should be intact and should point to the binary (`cut`  in this case) and so bash should not complain that it cannot locate the `cut` binary.

**Question**

How did the modification of the `PATH` affect the command substitution here?

Comment: I think you are confusing changes to `PATH` *in* a subshell with changes to `PATH` *inherited by* a subshell.

Comment: @chepner : Actually I overlooked the fact that PATH was an environment variable and it need not be exported for the changes to be effective.

Comment: Ah, OK. Keep in mind that "exporting" a variable really just means marking its name so that the *value* associated with that name is added to the environment of any child processes. An environment variable, being a variable initialized from the environment, is automatically exported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider below example:

```
$ export PS1='\$\$=$$ \$ '
$$=30862 $ a=123 # Note: No export a here.
$$=30862 $ echo $a
123
$$=30862 $ bash
$$=31133 $ echo $a # Subshell explicitly created does not have it.

$$=31133 $ exit
$$=30862 $ echo $(eval 'echo $a') # This subshell however does inherit it. The single quote ensures that this is not evaluated by parent shell.
123                               # echo $(echo $a) would probably cause $a to be evaluated by parent shell.
$$=30862 $
```

In short, subshells spawned by `$(...)` inherit same environment as parent shell, even if the variable is not exported. (Even `$$` is same as parent shell.)

Comment: Perfect ! Could you please cite `inherit same environment as parent shell,` from a documentation.

Comment: No probs.. Take your time.